# How can I merge two columns of data by row in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data of the form:

```
Account    | Product | Sales Price | List Price
Customer 1 | Product 1 | $10 | $30
Customer 1 | Product 2 | $20 | $20
Customer 2 | Product 2 | $15 | $20
Customer 3 | Product 1 | $15 | $30
Customer 3 | Product 2 | $15 | $20
... (more rows like that)
```

I want to generate a report that is a histogram of (sales price / list price) for Product 1 but only for those customers that have bought Product 1 AND Product 2.
I have some ideas on how to do this myself, but none of them seem particularly elegant nor straightforward to implement. Most of them involve reformatting the data into another sheet which is doable but I don't want to manually do it every time I re-run the report.

Is there a straightforward way to get the result that I want?

Comment: Can there be multiple rows for e.g. Customer 1 Product 1?

Comment: sounds like a job for pivot table

Comment: @Asu no, Customer1/Product1 is unique and will not repeat, though Customer1 may buy more than 1 product

Comment: @Raystafarian Probably, but I don't know how to do this sort of operation using a pivot table.

Comment: Give it a try! If you run into an issue, you can come back for help with that specific issue

Comment: Sorry, I'm abroad right now, so can't reply often. It sounds like there are also other products e.g. Product3, correct?